# PHP - how can I run a query on a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

A PHP multidimensional associative array is essentially the same as a data table kept in a database, right? Each row is a record, and each column is (or should be) the same data type.

Is there a way, perhaps a function library, to allow us to run SQL-type queries on this dataset?

Specifically, I would like to sort by any of the columns, and to return a subset (probably in another array) of the original dataset, based on criteria, such as "where the $filename element contains the string 'abcdx'".

Here's more application-specific information. I have a client who keeps many thousands of files in a sub-root directory on his website, so they are not accessible by anyone but those with the correct FTP login and password. I have a restricted-access page on his website that lists all these files, and gives download links. I would like to be able to sort the list by file name, extension, or size (all these elements are in the array), and allow the visitors to apply a filter, so if they are looking for specific files, the list will contain only those files matching the search criteria.

I am digging into creating objects (each listing), and making an array of those objects, but right now I'm looking for the best way to accomplish this.

I'm sure I can make this happen, but there's no question in my mind someone here knows far more about this than I, and can offer an elegant and more efficient solution that I would wind up kludging together. So thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: There's nothing built into PHP for doing this. Maybe there's a library that implements it, but I did a quick google search and didn't find anything. So I think you'll have to roll your own code.

Answer (score 2):

> A PHP multidimensional associative array is essentially the same as a data table kept in a database, right?

No. PHP implements nested arrays, not multi-dimensional arrays:

$a[0][0]=1;
   $a[1][1]=1;

Does not cause allocation for $a[0][1] and $a[1][0].

Any element is dereferenced using a tree search starting at the root array.

> Each row is a record, and each column is (or should be) the same data type

In a relational database table, yes. Not in a PHP array *even if it were multi dimensional*. In most languages which do implement multi-dimensional arrays, the "columns" must often be of consistent size such that they can be dereferenced by calculating their position, but they don't have to be the same type.

> Is there a way, perhaps a function library, to allow us to run SQL-type queries on this dataset?

That would need some sort of ability to define arbitrary data structures, a language parser or api, concurrency control mechanisms, an indexing capabilty and caching for large datasets and given the amount of code involved could not be efficiently relinked and invoked at runtime - it would have to run as a daemon. We already have all these capabilities in relational DBMS such as Postgresql, Oracle, Mariadb....

As to how best to apply this to your problem, using the directories as a data store does not scale well for the kind of operations you describe. But maintaining 2 datasets in different substrates is not simple either although its a lot easier if you've got administration access to the system and the system supports a notification/callback system such as inotify, but you've provided no information about the platform and privilege.

But if I were tasked with this I would start by looking at tools like owncloud